# fancybox called from a skel-layer menu not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to call a Fancybox inline content from a Skel-layer menu (based on this theme : http://templated.co/spatial)

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about1" class="fancybox fancybox.inline button small fit" >about</a></li>
    <ul>
</nav> 
<div id="Login" style="display:none; position:relative;">
    <p>blabla</p>
</div>
```

Everything works fine except when the menu become a "topsidemenu".

When I click on my "about" link the menu close but nothing happen.
there is a `clickToHide : false,`in the "init.js" script that I can put to `true` and then when I click on my "about" link the menu is not hiding but if I close it manualy (by clicking outside) the fancybox is open perfectly.

So what I hope from you is that you have a solution for me to avoid that "conflict" between Fancybox and the skel-layer menu :(

(some help on the Skel-layer menu https://github.com/n33/skel.old/blob/master/docs/skel-layers.pdf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself :)

I've added this code to my header (that close the menu when I click links with class `.closenav-link`)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
    // close navPanel
    $(".closenav-link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        skel.plugins.layers.toggle('navPanel');
    });
    //...
});
</script>
```

and then I've added the class `closenav-link` PLUS `skel-layers-ignore` to my link.

I found the `skel-layers-ignore` in the `skel-layers.js` (source : https://github.com/n33/skel.old/blob/master/src/skel-layers.js) by searching `clickToHide`, and this allowed me to ignore the skel-layer functions when I clicked my link !
Then I just had to close the menu by adding the `skel.plugins.layers.toggle('navPanel');` to my header AND VOILAAAAA :)

```
<a href="#Login" style="" class="closenav-link skel-layers-ignore fancybox button small fit" ><?php echo _('HOME-LOGIN'); ?></a>
```

Hope this will help someone sometime :)